# Как написать оптимизированный код для поиска 2-битовых разреженных чисел?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Есть задача: найти 10**6 двух-битовых чисел в Python, чтобы выполнение кода было разумным по времени.

Если решать в лоб:

```
from itertools import count

k = 1

for number in count(1):

    if k < (10**3 + 1):

        ones_counter = str(bin(number)).count('1')

        if ones_counter == 2:


            print(f'k: {k}')
            print(f'Число: {number}')
            print(f'Модуль: {number % 35184372089371}')
            print(f'Двоичное: {bin(number)}')

            print(f'---')

            k += 1
    else:
        break
```

, то на больших дистанциях это нецелесообразно гонять столько пустых переборов.

Есть зависимость:

`0b11, 0b101, 0b110, 0b1001`, итд,

где слева всегда идет 0b1, а дальше постоянно плавает 1 от правого края до левой 1. и как только она доходит до левой 1, то добавляется сразу в конце еще один символ и 1 начинает передвигаться справа влево, а между ними всегда 0.

Как это сдеалать?

Comment: что значит `count(1)` в строке `for number in count(1):` ?

Comment: согласен, не дописал - from itertools import count

Comment: Задача в чём - получить последовательность "
есть зависимость:" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def fun(n):
    high = 1
    while n > 0:
        low = 0
        while low < high:
            yield (1 << high) + (1 << low)
            n -= 1
            if n == 0:
                return
            low += 1
        high += 1
```

---

тесты:

```
In [5]: list(fun(10))
Out[5]: [3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 17, 18, 20, 24]

In [6]: %timeit list(fun(10**6))
536 ms ± 702 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
from itertools import count, islice

gen = ((1 << x) | (1 << y) for x in count() for y in range(x))

for x in islice(gen, 0, 10**6):
    print(bin(x))
```

Comment: красивое решение !

Comment: @MaxU зря вы свое удалили, не каждому захочется разбираться с функциональщиной, если есть простое императивное решение.

Comment: восстановил свое решение, но оно выглядит как костыль по сравнению с вашим... :)

Comment: @MaxU больше решений хороших и разных! :)

Comment: А что делает пустой count?

Comment: @eri генерирует последовательность от 0 до бесконечности

Answer (score 1):

Перечисляем суммы двух степеней двойки:

```
def gen():
    a = 1
    while True:
        b = 1
        while b < a:
            yield a + b
            b *= 2
        a *= 2


g = gen()
for _ in range(int(input())):
    print(next(g))
```

> ```
> $ echo 10 | python gen.py
> 3
> 5
> 6
> 9
> 10
> 12
> 17
> 18
> 20
> 24
> ```

Две с половиной секунды до миллиона:

> ```
> $ time echo 1000000 | python gen.py | wc -l
> 1000000
>
> real  0m2.461s
> user  0m2.448s
> sys   0m0.188s
> ```